# remove query string from homepage url

Tags: urls

I have created a wordpress site in localhost and now before few days I have moved it on live. Now when I opening my site it is taking `?i=1`(like http://example.com/?i=1) in homepage url. All other pages url is fine. It is http://example.com in admin dashboard's setting and in database options table. I did not added this url in wp-config.php,functions.php file. I want to remove this `?i=1`. How can I do this?

Comment: go to permalinks and save. then reload again

Comment: It could be getting added by your host - See this similar question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137815/there-is-i-2-in-my-wordpress-website-index-url